# Considering safety problems using "exec" php command

Tags: php, exec

I am using the `exec` php command to launch a jar file in my web server.
Is there any precautions that I have to adopt to prevent any safety issues?I mean,could be dangerous use the `exec` comand?

Comment: If there are any user defined input as an argument, then yes, it's dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you provide the argument for the function. If you are using a literal, the code is only vulnerable to developer-level mistakes and bad practices. However, if you will be passing a variable it all depends on the source of the parameter. I would suggest to always practice very safe approach in this scenario, utilizing all the available validation tools right before calling the exec function. From top of my head:

- checking if the user's privilege on the underlying operating system are not being leveraged by utilizing the system user running the PHP process (very often the web server user with quite extensive access),
- possibly, temporarily jailing the environment used for the exec command to provide the user only with the files and executables which are required,
- practice safe programming even if at the moment you know that the value of the passed parameter is not provided by the user or third party, but from other parts of the code; even though that might not be the case, in the future other parts of the system might change, allowing injection of shell scripts to underlying OS.