# Execute a batch file in php

Tags: php, batch-file

I would like to open a server and then execute a batch file through php.
That batch file is store in `c:\tools\patch.bat`.

I tried below code but it is not working.

```
$output = array();  
exec('$name -w c:\tools\ c:\tools\patch.bat',$output);
```

Here `$name` is the name of server and patch.bat is batch file.

Comment: `exec("$name -w c:\tools\ c:\tools\patch.bat",$output); ` Get rid of the single quotes.

Comment: ...and "not working" is not a useful diagnosis - see the FAQ, tell us what did happen.

Comment: Use `exec` with caution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163079/considering-safety-problems-using-exec-php-command

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could create a local bat file server_batch.bat:

```
$name -w c:\tools\ c:\tools\patch.bat
```

and then run it like this:

```
$output = array();  
exec('<path_to_batch>\server_batch.bat',$output);
```